# listview with imageview and visibility

Tags: android, listview, imageview, visibility

I'm making an application that parses text and images from the Internet and displays them in a `ListView`. This works fine.

In each of the rows of `ListView`, the `ImageView` has `GONE` visibility value.

I'm trying to, if a field of XML parsing has value "yes", set the `ImageView`'s visibility to `VISIBLE`.

```
public class MinAdapterSuscr extends BaseAdapter {

    //... 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_my_nets, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView net = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.net);
        ImageView home = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.enthome);
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 

        HashMap<String, String> onets = new HashMap<String, String>();
        onets = data.get(position);

        // añadiendo los valores al listview
        title.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(onets.get(netsActivity.KEY_NOMBRE_RED_SUSCR)));
        artist.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(onets.get(netsActivity.KEY_DESCR_RED_SUSCR)));
        nuevasEntradas.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml(onets.get(netsActivity.KEY_POR_VER_SUSCR)));
        String isHome = onets.get(netsActivity.KEY_ES_INICIO_SUSCR);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(netsActivity.KEY_AVATAR_RED_SUSCR), thumb_image);

        // Comprobación de si es red propia o de inicio
        if(isHome.equals("yes")) {
            home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i("looking",”home visible”);
        }

        return vi;  
    }
}
```

This works, but it shows results that seem random. Sometimes the `ImageView` is visible, sometimes not, but does not match the "yes" of the XML.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **else** part also in **if conition**,

```
if(isHome.equals("yes")) {
  home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  Log.i("looking",”home visible”);
}
else
{
  home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  Log.i("looking",”home gone”);
}
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: I did not give "else" the importance it deserves
now works correctly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `"yes"` and `"no"` states, otherwise the previous "yesses" are never turned off since the rows are recycled. (Please watch Android's Romain Guy discuss efficiency with [adapters and `getView()`](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html))

```
if(isHome.equals("yes")) {
    home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.i("looking",”home visible”);
}
else {
    home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```